# Is it alright to call IOS property accessors inside a view controller's loadview when initializing?

Tags: ios, properties, initialization

In my project I am creating UIViewControllers without IB and hence without nib files, so all of the controller content, visible or otherwise, is created programatically in **loadView:** . Therefore I am essentially "initializing" all my objects in **loadView:**. Is this the right thing to do? Or should I put all my initialization in **initWithNibName:bundle:**?

As it is I am creating instances of my UIView subviews in the controller's **loadView:** like so:

```
self.mySubView =  [[SubView alloc] initWithFrame:aframe];
[self.view addSubView:self.mySubView];
[self.mySubView release];
```

So I am instantiating several of these subviews using synthesized properties. And as I am not inside an initializer, I am creating these views by calling their accessors as above. But yet, it does feel like this is essentially initialization code and so perhaps I should be calling alloc/ init on my ivars directly and not through accessors, which then leads me to think that I should be doing this in **initWithNibName:bundle:**.

And if I am right to initialize objects in **loadView:**, should i really be using an accessor to alloc/ init?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

At the time `initWithNibName:bundle:` is called (and here I am assuming you are NOT using a nib file), your view controller's controlled view is not yet created. It get's created the first time `self.view` is referenced. It is good practice to not do this in the init method. As a result, it follows that it is also good practice to not create your sub views in the init method.

The first time `self.view` is referenced in any way, the `loadView` method is automatically called by the view controller. It is your job to programmatically create the controlled view at this time. It is perfectly OK to create your subviews in the `loadView` method, and if you follow the good practice I suggested, you will need to. But you should only reference `self.view` in the `loadView` method for the purpose of assigning the controlled view to it, which means you should only be referencing it exactly once in the `loadView` method.

You should not be doing this in the `loadView` method:

```
[self.view addSubView:self.mySubView];
```

This is because you are referencing the controlled view while you are in the method that is called to create it. `self.view` isn't created for you, you have to create it in the 'loadView` method.

Instead, use a local variable to create the controlled view, then assign that local variable to `self.view` at the end of the `loadView` method.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Create a view from scratch with a local variable, addsubviews to it, and assign it to the view controller's view? Why would I do that when i have a reference to my view controller's view through self.view? And the subviews I would be adding are my own UIView subclasses. Do I refer to them as self.mySubView in loadview: as they are properties?

Comment: Yes, create a view from scratch with a local variable, addsubviews to it, and assign it to the view controller's view. When `loadView` is called, there is no view assigned to `self.view`. You can reference your subview as you see fit. The only restriction (in the `loadView` method) is on the controlled view of the `UIViewController`, which i what `self.view` refers to.

Comment: OK on closer inspection, I have actually created a scroll view and have added this to self.view as a subview. I could have assigned this scroll view to self.view, but instead aded it to it. I don't think it matters either way. All my subviews are then added to the scroll view. So as I am alloc-initing lots of subviews, is it ok to do this in loadView? And when creating these do i refer to them through accessors or not?

Comment: When `loadView` is called, it is called for the specific purpose of you creating the controlled view. `self.view` does not exist at the start of the call to `loadView`. It is your job to create a view and assign it to `self.view`. If you want to create a scroll view, that's fine.

Comment: Sure claireware but that's not what I'm asking. In a nutshell, do I put any initialization code in initWithNibName: seeing as how i am creating everything programatically? If the answer is no, and that I should create everything from scratch in loadview:, well is it ok to use accessors or not when initializing properties?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. If you are loading from a NIB, you should not be overriding `loadView`, nor should you be initializing in the init method. Your programatic alterations to the view should be in `viewDidLoad`. I will change my answer.

Comment: I am not loading from a Nib file. Please read the question again